# cURL do not return with the correct type

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to connect to a REST API (to be specific it's the SedoMLS API), which is supposed to have a XML-type response, but when I do my cURL call to that API, it return only plain text.

Here is my current code:

```
$key = "abcd1234";
$basicAuth = base64_encode("$user:$pwd");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url?$function=$key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic $basicAuth", "Content-type: application/xml"], "Accept: application/xml"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if their documentations isn't clear and it doesn't really return a XML response. But I hope someone may have a hint on why it's not working as intended :p

Thanks in advance !

Edit : as asked in comment, here is what should be returned, and what is actually returned.
Shoud be returned according to the docs :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sedofault PUBLIC "-//sedo//DTD MLS 1.0//EN" "/dtd/sedomls.dtd">
<sedofault origin="xxx" entity="xxx">
  <request_id id="1234.abcd"/>
  <fault_code>E00000</fault_code>
  <fault_string>Failed to process requested operation</fault_string>
</sedofault>
```

What is actually returned :

```
E00000Failed to process requested operation
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what is returned

Comment: @RiggsFolly, here what should be returned:
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sedofault PUBLIC "-//sedo//DTD MLS 1.0//EN" "/dtd/sedomls.dtd">
<sedofault origin="xxx" entity="xxx">
  <request_id id="1234.abcd"/>
  <fault_code>E00000</fault_code>
  <fault_string>Failed to process requested operation</fault_string>
</sedofault>" and what is actually returned:
"E00000Failed to process requested operation"

Comment: Would be useful to put that in the question using the `edit`

Comment: `<fault_string>Failed to process requested operation</fault_string>`

Comment: As we dont know what you are trying to do, and if we did we would have to reach behind a Pay Wall to debug it, you will have to wait for someone that is also using this API

Comment: If you're looking at it in a browser, the XML will render and look like text. Try to view the source if that's true.

Comment: Use `header("Content-type: text/xml")` in the script. Then the browser will format the XML instead of treating it as HTML. But you should use `echo $result;` rather than `print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you display the result, the browser is treating it as HTML, so it doesn't show the tags. Use `htmlentities()` to encode the result so that the `<` and `>` characters will be shown literally.

```
$result = htmlentities(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now... It works, thanks a lot

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, the problem of viewing HTML/XML literally is something every runs into early on.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Accept header outside of the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER array.

Change this line :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic $basicAuth", "Content-type: application/xml"], "Accept: application/xml"]);
```

To :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic $basicAuth", "Content-type: application/xml", "Accept: application/xml"]);
```

**Edited** :
You can add `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);` also add error handler

Here is example :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url?$function=$key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic $basicAuth", "Content-type: application/xml", "Accept: application/xml"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

echo $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
print_r($xml);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: This must be a copying error, since the code as posted won't even run because of that syntax error.

Comment: It was indeed a copying error

Comment: yes it is.... @Ethan

Answer (score 0):

If you `echo` or `print_r` your XML result, and use a browser to see what you got, your browser is going to assume those XML tags are HTML tags, and not render them on the screen.

To see what you *actually* got, use the "view source" feature on your browser or use something like CURL or insomnia to test.